# How to convert string date interval to number of days or seconds (ISO_8601)?

Tags: python

Is there an easy way in python to transform a string representation of a date interval:

```
P1M
```

To a timestamp or a datetime object?

Basically I need to work with date intervals according to this ISO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Something similar to http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a third-party module called [isodate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate/) that may do what you want:

```
In [1]: from isodate import parse_duration

In [2]: parse_duration('P1M')
Out[2]: isodate.duration.Duration(0, 0, 0, years=0, months=1)
```

You can also convert this object into a `datetime.timedelta` object if necessary (providing a `start` or `end` parameter so that the proper duration can be calculated in terms of the provided date):

```
In [8]: import datetime

In [9]: d = parse_duration('P1M')

In [10]: d.todatetime(start=datetime.datetime.today())
Out[10]: datetime.timedelta(31)
```

Comment: Be careful with this, as the function can return different "ducks".  For example `parse_duration('P1Y').months` will work but `parse_duration('P365D').months` throws an AttributeError.

Comment: 0.5.0 version: renamed method todatetime on Duraction objects to totimedelta

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the string representation you can use `time` module's `strftime` and `strptime`

```
import time
sdate = 'Sat, 15 Dec 2012 04:01:02'
timestamp = time.strftime("%s", time.strptime(sdate, '%a, %b %d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Useful site: http://strftime.org/